# How to search for a specific file name then move all files after that file to another folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, search

Let's say I have 10 PDF files in a folder named c:\Temp
1440_021662_54268396_1.pdf
1440_028116_19126420_1.pdf
1440_028116_19676803_1.pdf
1440_028116_19697944_1.pdf
1440_028116_19948492_1.pdf
1440_028116_19977334_1.pdf
1440_028116_20500866_1.pdf
1440_028116_20562027_1.pdf
1440_028116_20566871_1.pdf
1440_028116_20573350_1.pdf

In my search, I know I am looking for a file that will match a specific number, for example **19676803** (I'm getting the number to search for from a SQL Query I'm running in my script) 
I know how to find that specific file, but what I need to be able to do is move all the files **after** the searched file has been found to another pre-defined folder.  So using the 10 PDFs above as the example files, I need to move all the files "after" the file named 1440_028116_19676803_1.pdf to another folder.  I know how to move files using PowerShell, just do not know how to do it after/from a specific file name.  Hope that makes sense.

```bsh
$batchNumCompleted = 'c:\Temp\'  
$lastLoanPrinted = $nameQuery.LoanNumber  
$fileIndex = Get-ChildItem -path $batchNumCompleted | where {$_.name -match $lastLoanPrinted}
```

Can anyone provide suggestions/help on accomplishing my goal?  I'm not able to provide all code written so far as it contains confidential information.  Thank you.

Comment: When you say "after", do you mean _all files_ after it in the default sort order, or all files that have the same _prefix_ (ie `1440_028116_`) but the last number is bigger?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I mean all files after it in the default sort order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.Where()` extension method in `SkipUntil` mode:

```bsh
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $batchNumCompleted
$filesToMove = $allFiles.Where({$_.Name -like '*19676803_1.pdf'}, 'SkipUntil') |Select -Skip 1
```

Remove the `Select -Skip 1` command if you want to move the file with `19676803` in the name as well

Comment: Didn't work, didn't produce any output. I changed the second line to this and it appears I'm getting the results I'm looking for...`code $filesToMove = $allFiles.Where({$_ -match $lastLoanPrinted}, 'SkipUntil') | Select -Skip 1`  Thank you for steering me in the right direction, most appreciated.